# Need help plugging in bounds in a u-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This is a really basic question but I'm just a little confused. I have this integral: $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^3tdt$$

I solved it by doing a u-sub:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos t(1-\sin^2t)dt$$

Let $u=\sin t$, then $du=\cos t dt$

So the bounds need to change:

$t=0 \implies u=0$ and $t=2\pi \implies u=0$

So then I get $$\int_{0}^{0}1-u^2du$$ which would equal 0.

I know that I can solve it indefinitely first and then plug in the bounds at the end but I'm just not sure what's wrong with my u-substitution

Comment: The integral is $0$, and the $u$-substitution reflects that. $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^3(t)dt=\int_0^\pi\cos^3(t)dt+\int_\pi^{2\pi}\cos^3(t)dt$, but $\cos^3(t+\pi)=-\cos^3(t)$.

Comment: but how did you know to split it up to two integrals? @KentaS

Comment: and how did you know that you needed to split it at $\pi$? @KentaS

Comment: Take a look at the graph of $\cos^3(t)$. You will observe an (anti-)symmetry around $t=\pi$.

Comment: The integral is clearly zero since $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{mi\theta}\,d\theta = 0$ for any integer, non-zero $m$, and $2\cos\theta=e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a standard integral.There is nothing wrong with your calculations the indefinite is[image]

and consequently the definite is zero! You can also use the formula $cos3x = 4 cos^{3}x - 3 cos x$ to get rid of the third power!!